# Lubuntu crashes on keyboard input

Tags: lubuntu, login, crash

I installed Lubuntu on a 2GB RAM laptop. I get to the login screen (which is reached without trouble). Though whenever I press a key on my keyboard, Lubuntu seems to crash as it just shuts down (it does show the logo with the dotted progressbar, seems like it is actually shutting down in a clean fashion). I am able to click on everything without a problem. It only happens when  I press a key on my keyboard, entering my password in this case. This is not a dual-boot setup. Any suggestions?

Edit: Specs

- RAM: 2GB DDR3
- CPU: Intel Atom
- Graphics: Intel HD Graphics
- Storage: 32GB SSD (MoBo solded)

Comment: Could be hardware but if it worked in a live session it should work. But if you installed using the alternative installer then it wouldn't have stressed the graphics, CPU, RAM enough to trigger a shutdown. Please edit and post your hardware specs.

Comment: Updated with the hardware.

Comment: How does it work in a live session? Which Lubuntu release/version? Use only supported releases.

Comment: Live version is working fine. It's the 16.10 release.